# When exporting PDF file from Indesgn, Why colors messed with one another?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I made a 10 pages file in In-Design, RGB space designed for web. Created some masters. After exporting (smallest file size as well as others too) to pdf the result gives me different tint of color on pages even if i used the same master. So, if page 2 uses Master A and page 4 uses the same master A, in PDF they have a different color, more like they have a different color management.

```
http://postimg.org/image/8yyw8c5pd/
```

Up is the page with wrong color. Page 1 uses the same master as the page 3 below (at page 3 you wont see number in this print screen) but their colors differ and I don't get it why. I still need this file the same colors everywhere and the right color is displayed at the page at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your page 1 has undergone transparency flattening while pages 2 and 3 haven't.

Check your page 1 for transparent objects or objects with any blending mode other than Normal.

Comment: i have nothing at blend mode, also i dont have any object and everything is set to narmal

Comment: Maybe your linked background is a layered PSD? I would count that as well.

Comment: thank you :) yes indeed i made psd to jpg and now works perfectly